# Whenever I try to execute the test cases from console by using NUnit Exe.I get Data source name not found and no default driver specified this error

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, odbc, nunit

[image: exection results]

[image: error]

Whenever I tried to Execute the test cases by NUnit exe. from Console It execute all but wherever the verification is there from database it gives me `ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified` this error in the report how to handle this, how do I set **Data Source**, but when I ran the test cases from the Visual Studio it does not gave me any **data Source** Error. In the result where there is verification from the database only that test cases are getting failed rest the test cases are getting pass. Could you please help me to solve this error and my database server is localhost only.

Comment: Have you done any research? what is the connection string?  how have you setup the DataDriven Unit Tests? why are you using a Console Project instead of a Test Project? The Magic GUIDs for Test Projects are needed: `{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}` - tip: after you ask a question stay online for 10 mins to see if anyone has follow up questions. This website is *very* active.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I have done researched from my side as I wanted to run my test cases but using NUnit Console as wanted to run by every night  automatically , I have added the code in batch file and the by task scheduler can execute that. there are connection Strings which I had specified already in the database it self and it is execution through the VS Perfectly then why not from Console.

Comment: Please show your research (so we don't suggest things you've already tried). Show the code in batch file? what is the connection string (tip it isn't stored in the database)?  how have you setup the DataDriven Unit Tests? why are you using a Console Project instead of a Test Project? **As I said, a Console app doesn't have the magic GUIDs of the Test Project...**

Comment: Its Test Project only wanted to execute through the Console. the batch file to initialise the exection `start nunit3-console.exe "D:\TFS\***\tests.dll" --where "class =~ 'Tests'"` and it execute the the test cases and and there are some test cases where the verification is with the database only that is giving me that error.

Comment: If it is just *some* tests fail then compare the configuration of the tests that fail vs the ones that work. Most likely a connection string issue.

Comment: I have done that the test cases which we are testing for database verification that are getting fail and rest where we don't have any database verification we are not getting any error. do I need to create System DSN for this error but from visual studio all test cases are executing.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include this details. Show screenshots of the tests that work vs ones that fail. I'm starting to exhaust efforts... can you also read this: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the execution report ..